# Cant access BIOS or boot after pm-hibernate on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: boot, bios, hibernate, acer-aspire, ubuntu-15.10

**ACER ASPIRE 4560-Sb601 - Ubuntu 15.10**

I executed the command "sudo pm-hibernate" on Ubuntu 15.10 and could not access BIOS or boot anymore.

Grub2 appears, but boot stops with the following lines:

> Loading Linux 4.2.0-34-generic ...
>
> Loading initial ramdisk ...

What I already did:

1. I typed F2, F12, DEL and other keys at boot: not shows BIOS Setup goes to grub menu
2. I typed F2, F12, DEL and other keys at boot without HD: not shows BIOS Setup
3. I tryed a bootable ubuntu on a dvd: do nothing
4. I tryed a bootable ubuntu on a dvd without HD: shows grub but do nothing more
5. I tryed a bootable ubuntu on a pendrive: do nothing
6. I tryed a bootable ubuntu on a pendrive without HD: shows the following

> SYSLINUX 6.03 EDD 2014-10-06 Copyright (C) 1994-2014 H. Peter Anvin et al
>
> Failed to load ldlinux.c32
>
> Boot failed: please change disks and press a key to continue.

What should I do to fix it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed!!!

Solution:

> I just removed the battery and kept down the power button about 20 seconds,
>   that was enough to get back BIOS setup access. Then, just waited for
>   grub, selected Ubuntu's advantage options and the first available option with "(recovery mode)". Turned off again and could start normally.

This solution was reached with trials and erros. Maybe there's something on the manual.

Never more I gonna try hibernate in Ubuntu.

Thanks.